# Facebook APP - How do I make my Facebook App Live

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Am new to Facebook related stack. So, please bear if its a dumb question.

I created a Facebook App but I couldn't able to find the option to make my APP Live. Do I need to submit it for review and then only I can able to make it Live?

[image]

Also am trying to do a Facebook messaging using [send API.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/send-api/#recipient) Am getting "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: messages".

[image]

Am I missing something? Please help.

Comment: Your API call is missing the object (page) before the edge (`messages`)  you want to access. In most cases, that should just be `me` (page id will be determined from the page token used.)

Answer (score 0):

> Also am trying to do a Facebook messaging using send API. Am getting
> "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist:
> messages"

Your URL should be in this format

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/me/messages?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

This means you're missing the `/me` object in your call. Also since, it's a POST request you need to attach a body with the following params to the call.

```
"messaging_type": "<MESSAGING_TYPE>",
  "recipient": {
    "id": "<PSID>"
  },
  "message": {
    "text": "hello, world!"
  }
```

> Do I need to submit it for review and then only I can able to make it
> Live?

According to the page you linked, you need to request `pages_messaging` permission and that requires App Review in order for this Send API to work in your app.
Additionally, If you want to test this in development mode, you can give a role to the user(as a developer, tester, or analytics user) you're trying to message and test with them as mentioned on the page you linked:

> Apps in Development Mode, are restricted to message people that have a
> role in the app. Additionally, Pages in unpublished status will only be
> allowed to message people with a role on the Page.